# JavaScript создает угрозу

Tags: javascript

**index.html:**

```
<script language="JavaScript">window.location.href="http://mysite.com"</script>
```

Проверяю index.html через Avast, и тот начинает "нежно, чуть ли шепча" говорить, что обнаружена угроза. Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Это на какой странице? У вас перенаправление принудительное идет. И может быть даже циклическое.

Answer (score 1):

Avast сам по себе тупой антивирус, может глючит...
Тэг `language` не используется (устарел давно), рекомендуется `type`, хотя если там JavaScript, то его указывать не нужно, ибо по умолчанию он!
Может ругаться на то, что такой прямой редирект иногда (чаще чем хотелось бы) используется в дорвеях.
А ещё может аваст определяет ссылку как ядовитую (опасный сайт в его базе).